# how to raise OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, optimistic-locking

Unable to catch optimistic lock exception.

one way to raise  OptimisticLockException is by using em.flush()

```
try{
   //some enitity
   em.flush()
  }
catch(OptimisticLockException ole){}
```

but i dont think this is best solution beacuse in this full database is flush.

another work around is by catching `EJBException` and find `RollBackException` in that ..

```
       try{
            // some code
        }
       catch (EJBException ex) {

          if (ex.getCausedByException().getCause().toString().
              indexOf("javax.transaction.RollbackException")!= -1){
                   // do work
              }     
          }
       }
```

Please help do you have any other idea or tell me which way is better.

Comment: Why do you want to raise a specific exception that sounds like it isn't one an app should be raising?  But if you decide it's appropriate can you not just `throw new OptimisticLockException()` in your code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first way is a reasonable way if you want to catch OptimisticLockException and refresh your data or retry your operation. As for the second way, if the current transaction is not active, there is no RollbackException thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    getEntityRepository().update("Some Persistence Obj");
}
catch (EJBException e)
{
    if (e.getCause() instanceof OptimisticLockException)
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```